# How to assert in django pytest when matching query does not exists

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

How to assert in django pytest when **matching query does not exists**

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_abc_pending_response(sent_xyz):
    #Test count is 1
    rider_pending_response()
    sent_orders.refresh_from_db()
    #Test count is 0 or matching query does not exists
    assert XYZ.ObjectDoesNotExist #(This assert is not working)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `with` context proccesor. Like this;

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_abc_pending_response(sent_xyz):
    #Test count is 1
    rider_pending_response()
    sent_orders.refresh_from_db()
    #Test count is 0 or matching query does not exists
    with self.assertRaises(YourModel.ObjectDoesNotExist):
         YourModel.objects.get(key=value)
```